# Splitting tables with composite primary key on EF Core database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to split a table in an EF Core repository which has a composite primary key. But its generating an InvalidOperationException saying that it can't find a primary key on the derived table.

**'The entity type 'DetailedOrder' requires a primary key to be defined.'**

To test it, I took the sample code for table splitting from the [EntityFramework.Docs repository](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/samples/core/Modeling/TableSplitting/TableSplittingContext.cs) and modified it to include a composite PK:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int Rev { get; set; }
    public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DetailedOrder DetailedOrder { get; set; }
}

public class DetailedOrder : Order
{
    public string BillingAddress { get; set; }
    public string ShippingAddress { get; set; }
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}

public class TableSplittingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DetailedOrder> DetailedOrders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServer(@"Server = 20.0.5.64\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=EFSamples;User Id = cp; Password=crest1*");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DetailedOrder>()
                        .ToTable("Orders")
                        .HasBaseType((string)null)
                        .Ignore(o => o.DetailedOrder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(
                entity =>
                    {
                        entity.HasKey(ck => new { Id = ck.OrderId, ck.Rev });
                        entity.ToTable("Orders")
                            .HasOne(o => o.DetailedOrder).WithOne()
                            .HasForeignKey<Order>(o => new { Id = o.OrderId, o.Rev });
                    });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The entity type 'DetailedOrder' requires a primary key to be defined.

The (composite) PK must be explicitly defined for *all* entities where the PK cannot be derived automatically by the EF Core [naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys#conventions). The sample is using a PK named `Id`, that's why it doesn't need additional configuration.

The correct configuration of the posted model with table splitting should be like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DetailedOrder>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasBaseType((string)null)
        .Ignore(o => o.DetailedOrder);
    entity.HasKey(o => new { o.OrderId, o.Rev }); // <--
    entity.ToTable("Orders");
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(o => new { o.OrderId, o.Rev }); // <--
    entity.ToTable("Orders");
    entity.HasOne(o => o.DetailedOrder).WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<Order>(o => new { Id = o.OrderId, o.Rev });
});
```

In fact the only difference between the reqular one-to-one relationship and table splitting is the `ToTable` fluent configuration specifying one and the same table for the principal and dependent entity. The other parts of the entity configuration should be the same as with no table splitting.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. 
I cleaned up my composite key on the DetailedOrder and added in the matching key on the Order entity, but it is now giving me an error:

A key cannot be configured on 'DetailedOrder' because it is a derived type. The key must be configured on the root type 'Order'. If you did not intend for 'Order' to be included in the model, ensure that it is not included in a DbSet property on your context, referenced in a configuration call to ModelBuilder, or referenced from a navigation property on a type that is included in the model.'

Comment: Hmm, may be the `HasBase` trick doesn't work. But in your real scenario you want be inheriting another entity class, don't you? Another thing that comes to my mind, moving `HasKey` line *after* `HasBase` / `Ignore` should probably eliminate the new exception

Comment: Just tested it, and can confirm that is updated is the correct configuration sequence for this scenario and it works.